# Core Data executeFetchRequest: not returning saved data

Tags: ios, xcode, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I have this method `getLevelInformation` that sends a fetch request to my Core Data store to acquire information about this `int` called `_bestMoveCount` based on two parameters, level and type of level (level being any `int` from 0-99, and type of level from 1-4).  If the predicate hasn't been located, a new object is created for specific level and best move (and type of level if it hasn't been created already).  Otherwise, I retrieve the best movement `NSNumber` and eventually convert it to my `NSInteger` instance var `_bestMoveCount`.

My problem:  it appears that `_levelInformation` (by the time it checks to see if there is anything contained in the specific fetch) is always empty when I replay one of my levels (which it shouldn't, because I save the newly created data).  When I go back to play the level again, and put a breakpoint at the `if` statement, I take a look at `_levelInformation` after the `executeFetchRequest:` method.  Here's what I see:

```
    <Score: 0x1cd68a40> (entity: Score; id: 0x1cd68470 <x-coredata:///Score/t510F3599-89E9-4A57-B9BC-34DE0131E2142> ; data: {
        bestMovement = 0;
        bestTime = 0;
        level = 0;
        overallScore = 0;
        typeOfLevel = 0;
    })
```

At this point, if I clicked on level 2, `bestMovement` should be something like 18, `level` should be 1, `typeOfLevel` should be 2 (I'm playing my second type).  Any thoughts as to why this isn't saving my data?

```
    - (void)getLevelInformation {
       NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
       _managedObjectContext = [(AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]
                                                               delegate] managedObjectContext];
       NSEntityDescription *entityDescription = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Score" inManagedObjectContext:_managedObjectContext];
       [fetchRequest setEntity:entityDescription];
       NSNumber* levelNumber = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:_currentLevel];
       NSNumber* typeNumber = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:_level];
       NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K == %@ AND %K == %@",
                          @"level", levelNumber, @"typeOfLevel", typeNumber];
       [fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];
       NSError *error = nil;
       _levelInformation = [[_managedObjectContext
                             executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error] lastObject];
       // the only way this fails is if the level the player is on has never been accessed
       // OR RATHER, if the player never actually finished the level (thus never getting
       // a best move count, best time, and overall score.
       if (!_levelInformation) {
          _levelInformation = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Score"
                                                inManagedObjectContext:_managedObjectContext];
          [_levelInformation setValue:levelNumber forKey:@"level"];
          if (![_levelInformation valueForKey:@"typeOfLevel"]) {
             [_levelInformation setValue:typeNumber forKey:@"typeOfLevel"];
          }
          [_levelInformation setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:0] forKey:@"bestMovement"];
          if (![_levelInformation.managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
             NSLog(@"Unable to save managed object context.");
             NSLog(@"%@, %@", error, error.localizedDescription);
          }
       }
       _levelInformation.bestMovement = [_levelInformation valueForKey:@"bestMovement"];
       _bestMoveCount = [_levelInformation.bestMovement integerValue];

    }
```

Forgot to mention.  After the level is completed I save the new data again.

```
    - (void)saveTheBestMove {
       [_levelInformation setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:_bestMoveCount] forKey:@"bestMovement"];
       NSError *error;
       [_managedObjectContext save:&error];
    }
```

Comment: Can you check if there is error details in _levelInformation = [[_managedObjectContext
                             executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error] lastObject];

Comment: No, no error.   What is returned and stored in `_levelInformation` I provided up top...with all my attributes set to 0.  Really, I get no errors in this entire process.  Every time I repeat a level though, my best movement score is not saved.  That's all.

Comment: Frank can you check if Managed Object Has any Changes to Save before you really save the best movement. Something like this NSError *error;
if ([managedObjectContext hasChanges] && ![managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
    // TODO: handle this error better.
    NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
    abort();
}

Comment: Yea still nothing, the same results as before.  Any other thoughts?

Comment: Still no solution...haven't figured out the reason for this behavior.  Anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Can you open the table in sqlite manager, and check if the data is getting modified there. Also, may be the fetched object is not proper. basically check the sqlite db if you can see some faulty behaviour there. Also check [_managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error] is returning multiple object, check whether you need firstObject instead of lastObject, like print all the objects. See that you are trying to modify desired object only.